# consulta SQL para somar Linhas e exibir em duas Colunas no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de exibir o somatório de varias linhas, só que em duas colunas. Todas as informações estão na mesma tabela. Só que os critérios mudam.
Ex: quero o `SUM` de uma coluna com `WHERE` especifico e quero o `SUM` da mesma coluna só que com outro `WHERE`. E esses valores mostrados em duas Colunas (SUM1 E SUM2).

Estou usando assim, mas vem em linhas:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(ITEMSAIDA.NVLRUNITARIO), 
     ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC, 
     ITEMSAIDA.NCODVENDEDOR 
  FROM ITEMSAIDA 
  WHERE 
     ITEMSAIDA.CNPJ = 'XX.XXX.XXX/0001-XX' AND 
     VENDEDOR.CNPJ =  'XX.XXX.XXX/0001-XX' AND 
     (
        ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 13 OR 
        ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 24
     ) 
  GROUP BY ITEMSAIDA.NCODVENDEDOR, ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC
```

Obrigado

Comment: podes usar o [`case when`](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/utilizando-select-case-com-mysql).. mas não tá muito clara a condição de cada um. detalha melhor a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que SUM1 seja referente a ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 13 e SUM2 a ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 24, pois você não especificou os critários para cada uma das somas, pode tentar algo do tipo:

```
SELECT 
     CASE SUM(WHEN ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 13 THEN ITEMSAIDA.NVLRUNITARIO ELSE 0) END AS SUM1, 
     CASE SUM(WHEN ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC = 24 THEN ITEMSAIDA.NVLRUNITARIO ELSE 0) END AS SUM2, 
     ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC, 
     ITEMSAIDA.NCODVENDEDOR 
  FROM ITEMSAIDA 
  WHERE 
     ITEMSAIDA.CNPJ = 'XX.XXX.XXX/0001-XX' AND 
     VENDEDOR.CNPJ =  'XX.XXX.XXX/0001-XX'
  GROUP BY ITEMSAIDA.NCODVENDEDOR, ITEMSAIDA.NCODLINHAMERC;
```

Comment: e o perguntador some ...